# SQL Server FOR XML - more same child node in one node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need this XML output from one table (I have view, I have a view, but it doesn't matter):

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TabKmenZbozi](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nazev1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [GroupGoodsID] [int] NULL,
    [GroupGoodsName] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data for example

```
INSERT INTO TabKmenZbozi (Nazev1, GroupGoodsID, GroupGoodsName) 
VALUES
    ('2117 OF SWEDEN 7709901', 1, 'Meals'),
    ('BLIZZARD DOUBLE', 2, 'Drinks'),
    ('Test Test 1111', 1, 'Meals')
```

I need this output

```xml
<data type="TEST" destination="FILE" version="1">
  <content>
    <group Deleted="0">
        <GroupGoods ids="1" name="Meals"/>
        <GroupGoods ids="2" name="Drinks"/>
    </group>
      <goodsCard Deleted="2">
        <item ids="2217" idsGroup="2" plu="43"/>
        <item ids="2218" idsGroup="1" plu="43"/>
        <item ids="2219" idsGroup="1" plu="43"/>
        <item ids="2220" idsGroup="1" plu="43"/>
      </goodsCard>
  </content>
</data>
```

I tried something like this

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT 
    (SELECT 
       (SELECT TOP 10  
                 G.ID AS '@ids',
                 G.Nazev1 AS '@name'
        FROM TabKmenZbozi G
      FOR XML PATH('item'), TYPE)
    FOR XML PATH('goodsCard'), TYPE)
  FOR XML PATH ('content'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('data'), TYPE;
```

It's good for `goodsCard`.

Output:

```xml
<data>
   <content>
      <goodsCard>
         <item ids="2" name="Test Test 1111" />
         <item ids="3" name=" BLIZZARD DOUBLE" />
         <item ids="5" name="2117 OF SWEDEN 7709901" />
      </goodsCard>
   </content>
</data>
```

But I don't know how to add "group" node and attributes to nodes
for example

```xml
<data type="TEST" destination="FILE" version="1">
```

Thank you for your help

Solved with Charlieface post and my longer code...

```
SELECT 
  'TEST' AS '@type',
  'FILE' AS '@destination',
  '1' AS '@version',
   (
    SELECT
      (
       SELECT
         '0' AS '@DELETED',
         (
         SELECT
           TKZ.ID AS 'GroupGoods/@ids',
           TKZ.Nazev1 AS 'GroupGoods/@nazev'
         FROM
           dbo.TabKmenZbozi AS TKZ
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         )
       FOR XML PATH('group'), TYPE
      ),
      (
       SELECT
         '2' AS '@DELETED',
         (
         SELECT TOP 10
           TKX.ID AS 'goodsCard/@ids',
           TKX.Nazev1 AS 'goodsCard/@nazev'
         FROM
           dbo.TabKmenZbozi AS TKX
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         )
       FOR XML PATH('goodsCard'), TYPE
      )
    FOR XML PATH('content'), TYPE
   )
FOR XML PATH('data'), TYPE;
```

Comment: You could use a powershell script and query the database with PS and then create the XML output.

Comment: You've already shown that you know how to add attributes to the `item` elements, why can you not do the same for the other elements?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77769059/edit) your question to include the table's schema and some sample data - as T-SQL - so that we can see how you need to query it to separately produce the `GroupGoods` and `item` elements.

Comment: I (and I expect several others) may be able to provide an answer, but not without the table schema and sample data needed to understand the required mapping and to test any potential solution. Your current test result doesn't even have the same data as your desired result.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: edited it and added the data.

Comment: Unclear how the desired result is derived. Where does `2220` come from for example? And in fact where do most of the attribute values come from? Are they hardcoded? Like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/0RqSPBoo

Comment: Your table schema and sample data is incomplete. The table is missing an `ID` column. Values in your desired results include attributes like `"2217"` and `plu="43"` that are not in your sample data. The number of rows does not even match. If you would like further assistance, please fix.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to nest so deeply. To nest attributes and elements in a single sub-node, you can just make the column names `outerNode/innerNode` or `outerNode/@attributeName`

`@` in a column name will get you an attribute.

```sql
SELECT
  [@type] = 'TEST',
  [@destination] = 'FILE',
  [@version] = '1',
  [content/group/@Deleted] = '0',
  [content/group] = (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      [@ids] = GroupGoodsID,
      [@name] = GroupGoodsName
    FROM TabKmenZbozi tkz
    FOR XML PATH('GroupGoods'), TYPE
  ),
  [content/goodsCard/@Deleted] = '2',
  [content/goodsCard] = (
    SELECT
      [@ids] = ID,
      [@idsGroup] = GroupGoodsID,
      [@plu] = '43'
    FROM TabKmenZbozi tkx
    FOR XML PATH('item'), TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH('data'), TYPE;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/EdU9l-rb)

Comment: Super. It's functional. I ended up with a longer solution. Yours is better.

Answer (score -2):

Here is powershell solution

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$xml = @'
<data type="TEST" destination="FILE" version="1">
  <content>
    <group Deleted="0">
        <GroupGoods ids="1" name="Meals"/>
        <GroupGoods ids="2" name="Drinks"/>
    </group>
      <goodsCard Deleted="2">
        <item ids="2217" idsGroup="2" plu="43"/>
        <item ids="2218" idsGroup="1" plu="43"/>
        <item ids="2219" idsGroup="1" plu="43"/>
        <item ids="2220" idsGroup="1" plu="43"/>
      </goodsCard>
  </content>
</data>
'@

$xInDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xml)
$content = $xInDoc.Descendants('content')[0]

$xmlTemplat = '<data><content><goodsCard></goodsCard></content></data>'
$xOutDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xmlTemplat)
$goodsCard = $xOutDoc.Descendants('goodsCard')[0]

foreach($groupGoods in $content.Descendants('GroupGoods'))
{
   $id = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::New([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('ids'), $groupGoods.Attribute('ids').Value)
   $name = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::New([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('name'), $groupGoods.Attribute('name').Value)
   $item = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::New([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('item'), @($id,$name))
   $goodsCard.Add($item)
}
$xOutDoc.Save($filename)
```

Xml Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <content>
    <goodsCard>
      <item ids="1" name="Meals" />
      <item ids="2" name="Drinks" />
    </goodsCard>
  </content>
</data>
```

Comment: I dont think this answers the question. All you did is reproduce what the OP was was able to create, but starting with the desired output as your input. The OP needs to create the full xml document you assumed in your script _from sql_

Comment: @Xedni : Read the OPS question again.  I think you misunderstood.  The OP has a XML file stored in the Database.  The input is the Database XML file just like what I used.